# Accessing Database created in one activity in another Activity

Tags: android, sqlite, null, instance

For some odd reason I can't seem pull off information off my database created in one activity in another. I had the same issues with a static arraylist. Thought it would be much easier using a database but it keeps crashing. My DB instance is always null in the next activity even though I called it before pulling off any information. Here is my function in fragment class

```
private void populateListView(){
    Cursor cursor = myDatabase.getAllData();
    String[] fromfieldNames = new String[]{StudentDBOpenHelper.KEY_ID,StudentDBOpenHelper.ITEM_NAME_COLUMN};
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] {R.id.textView_itemNumber,R.id.textView_itemName};
    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
    myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
            R.layout.individualview,cursor,fromfieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
    ListView myList = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.courseListXML);
    myList.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
}//USed to populate list view
```

The function itself is placed outside of onCreateView and onViewCreated but called in onViewCreated.

Here is my database helper class

```
public class StudentDBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";

public static final String ITEM_NAME_COLUMN = "ITEM_NAME_COLUMN";

public static final String ITEM_CATEGORY_COLUMN = "ITEM_CATEGORY_COLUMN";

public static final String ITEM_GRADE_COLUMN = "ITEM_GRADE_COLUMN";


public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myItemDatabase.db";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "ItemInfo";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE ="create table " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, " +
        ITEM_NAME_COLUMN + " text, " +
        ITEM_CATEGORY_COLUMN + " text, "
        +ITEM_GRADE_COLUMN + " integer);";




/*
public StudentDBOpenHelper(Context context,String name,
                           SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,int version)   {
 super(context,name,factory,version);



}
*/

public StudentDBOpenHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);


}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL((DATABASE_CREATE));
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    Log.w("TaskDBAdapter", "Upgrading from version" +
            oldVersion + ",which will destroy all old data");

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + DATABASE_TABLE);
    onCreate(db);

}

public boolean insertData(String firstname,String lastname,String credits){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(); //instance of class
    contentValues.put(ITEM_NAME_COLUMN,firstname);//2 parameters(Column name in which you
    //you want to insert data
    // and second is the value itself
    contentValues.put(ITEM_CATEGORY_COLUMN, lastname);
    contentValues.put(ITEM_GRADE_COLUMN, credits);

    long result = db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,contentValues);
    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }
    else {

        return true;
    }
}//ends insertData functin

public Cursor getAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + DATABASE_TABLE,null);
    return result;
}//ends cursor


public boolean updateData(String id,String firstname,String lastname,String credits){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(KEY_ID,id);
    contentValues.put(ITEM_NAME_COLUMN,firstname);//2 parameters(Column name in which you
    //you want to insert data
    // and second is the value itself
    contentValues.put(ITEM_CATEGORY_COLUMN, lastname);
    contentValues.put(ITEM_GRADE_COLUMN, credits);

    db.update(DATABASE_TABLE,contentValues,"_id = ?",new String[]{id});

    return true;
}

public Integer deleteData(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE,"_id = ?",new String[] {id});
}
}
```

Comment: give some code of where you initialized the db

Comment: Do you actually create a new instance of StudentDBOpenHelper in the next activity before calling any of its methods? Plus, you say 'next activity' but later you speak fragment: so, is it a proper activity or a fragment activity?

Comment: I initialized the db inside the Fragment class before the onCreateView and onViewCreated  like this 

StudentDBOpenHelper myDatabase;

Comment: My next activity inflates the Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to initialize your database is as following:

```
StudentDBOpenHelper myDatabase= new StudentDBOpenHelper(this);
```

use `this` as argument if it's an Activity, `getContext()` if it's a Fragment.

Comment: I inserted data into the database in my first activity, Would this be the proper way to access the database in the next activity?

Comment: @Carlitos a Database in Android is persistent, which means that once data is stored it will remain stored until the user edits/deletes the data (if you implement such method) or until the app is uninstalled or it's data is cleared in Settings.
So, creating a new Db instance in another activity is the way to go.

Comment: I tried creating a new db instance in the other activity but it keeps saying that the database is empty when I try to access it.

Comment: @Carlitos can you write the precise message? Do you see this in logcat or where?

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.Cursor com.example.carlitos.mycourseapplicationupdate.StudentDBOpenHelper.getAllData()' on a null object reference

Comment: This is how I initialized my instance of the database in the fragment
StudentDBOpenHelper myDatabase;

Comment: Tried doing the getContext() method but keeps saying it requires API 23 so I used getActivity() and even that it crashes

Comment: @Carlitos the NullPointerException is cause by your incorrect initialization. There must be a problem with something else in you project, because I recompiled my app initializing the database in a fragment like in the answer I gave you with both getContext() and getActivity() and it works perfectly.